# PowerPoint 2019 for Windows Macro Error: Compile Error: Label not defined

Tags: vba, powerpoint

So I made a code like this:

```
Private Sub MSCPByn_Click()
    If Slide 24.MSCP = "test" Then
        GoTo Slide25
    Else
        GoTo Slide26
    End If
End Sub
```

And when I tried it it didn't work, resulting in the error: "Compile Error: Label not defined", highlighting the 5th line.

What to do?

Comment: Do you have a label named "Slide26"?

Comment: That's a slide.

Comment: GoTo expects a label so you'll need to figure out how to use Slide26 to accomplish what you need.  Perhaps check out the properties of Slide26?

Comment: Actually, I got this after some tries:        ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide 26